# How to optimize Hive query on table with dynamic partitioning

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have to partition table according to date and hour from `resultdate` field which is in the format `2/5/2013 9:24:00 AM`.

I am using dynamic partitioning with date & hour and doing an

```
insert overwrite table partition(date, hour)
{
select x,y,z, date , hour
}
from table 1.
```

I have about 1.5 million records, and it is taking about 4 hrs to complete. Is this normal, what would be some ways to optimize?

Answer (score 0):

increase the cluster size otherwise it will take much time.

Answer (score 0):

this is not normal, except if you are working in a virtual machine with 1 node :) .. Try setting this flag

```
set hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition=false;
```

I am not sure why it is set to true by default in some distros.

Answer (score 0):

There are many scenarios to this,

- Check whether TEZ engine can be used to make your execution time better.
- whether the way we store the file can be changed, RC Format might help.
- optimizing the hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions &   hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions to a optimal value.
- Increasing the cluster is also good ( if feasible )